# How to aggregate the data group by date without using group by?

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-athena

I have a query something like this:

```
SELECT id, site, clicks, approved, year, month, day
FROM df
```

*id* and *clicks* are integer; *site, year, month, day* are string; and *approved* is a boolean.

Now, I want to see the number of clicks for each month/year. To do this, I want to sum the clicks by grouping the year and month.

How to do this?

Comment: Hint:  `GROUP BY`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe concat() function is the point.

```
select x.*
into #df
from
(
SELECT 1 as id, 'a' as site, 23 as clicks, 1 as approved, '2020' as year, '1' as    month, '1' as day
UNION ALL
SELECT 2 as id, 'a' as site, 1 as clicks, 1 as approved, '2020' as year, '1' as month,     '1' as day
UNION ALL
SELECT 3 as id, 'a' as site, 3 as clicks, 1 as approved, '2020' as year, '3' as month,     '1' as day
UNION ALL
SELECT 4 as id, 'a' as site, 11 as clicks, 1 as approved, '2020' as year, '4' as     month, '1' as day
UNION ALL
SELECT 5 as id, 'a' as site, 345 as clicks, 1 as approved, '2020' as year, '5' as     month, '1' as day
UNION ALL
SELECT 6 as id, 'a' as site, 88 as clicks, 1 as approved, '2020' as year, '6' as     month, '1' as day
UNION ALL
SELECT 7 as id, 'a' as site, 1 as clicks, 1 as approved, '2020' as year, '12' as     month, '1' as day
) x;

select 
    concat(year, '_', month) yyyy_mm
    , sum(clicks) clicks_total
from #df
group by 
    concat(year, '_', month)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try using `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT year, month, SUM(clicks) AS total
FROM df
GROUP BY year, month;
```

Side note: I don't know whether the table name `df` be short for data frame, or if you are using R or Python here.  But, in pure SQL it is desirable to just maintain a single date column, rather than storing year, month, and day as separate components.